# Error when writing a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a simple Chrome extension to cycle through open tabs.

I am getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: startTabCycle is not defined

...in my popup.js file:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
var stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn');

// Add event listeners to the buttons
startBtn.addEventListener('click', startTabCycle);
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', stopTabCycle);
  });
```

My popup.html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tab Cycling Control</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Tab Cycling Control</h1>
  <form id="controlForm">
    <button type="button" id="startBtn">Start</button>
    <button type="button" id="stopBtn">Stop</button>
  </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

My manifest.json file is:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Tab Cycling",
"version": "1.0",
"permissions": ["tabs", "windows"],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
"browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
}
```

My background.js file is:

```
let tabCycleIntervalId = null; // Track the interval ID

function startTabCycle() {
  chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
    let index = 0;
    const interval = 10000; // Interval in milliseconds

    function cycleTabs() {
      chrome.tabs.update(tabs[index].id, { active: true });

      // Re-enter full-screen mode after switching tabs
      chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (currentWindow) {
       // chrome.windows.update(currentWindow.id, { state: 'fullscreen' });
      });

      index = (index + 1) % tabs.length;
    }

    // Start tab cycling and store the interval ID
    tabCycleIntervalId = setInterval(cycleTabs, interval);
    cycleTabs(); // Immediately switch to the first tab
  });
}

function stopTabCycle() {
  // Clear the interval when stopping the tab cycling
  clearInterval(tabCycleIntervalId);
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
  if (message.action === 'startTabCycle') {
    startTabCycle();
  } else if (message.action === 'stopTabCycle') {
    stopTabCycle();
  }
});
```

Can anyone help point out what I've done wrong please?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: You need to understand how to pass messages from [your content scripts to your background scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/).

Comment: Not having written any browser (Chrome) extensions, I'd say that `popup.js` can't "see" `startTabCyc.le` that's defined in `background.js` because it's not been included in `popup.html`. But, that doesn't mean you should. You should probably send a message to trigger it.